# Changing css style of element

Tags: jquery, css

I want to change a style of the `.check-media` but this does not work. How to fix it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .check-media{
        width:500px;
        background-color:gray;
    }
</style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
    if($('.check-media').width() <= 768) {
        console.log('You are in width: 768px');
    }else{
        console.log('You are out of width: 768px');
    }

    if($(window).width() < 768) {
        console.log('screen.width is LESS then 768px');
        $('.check-media').css({"background-color":"blue"});
    } else {
        console.log('screen.width is MORE then 768px');
        $('.check-media').css({"background-color":"red"});
    }
</script>

</head>

<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<div class='check-media'>check-media contentn</div>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wrap you code in document-ready handler. http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: @Satpal it works but how to make it dynamicaly?

Comment: @rozero what did you mean by dynamic?

Comment: @RinoRaj depending of changing browser screen with

Comment: Assuming you want to amend the layout of the page based on the screen size, use CSS media queries as they were designed for this exact purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using CSS alone via Media Queries:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .check-media {
    background-color: blue !important;
  }
}

.check-media {
    background-color: red;
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/m0wf8ye4/) - change window size to see it in action.

Relying on Javascript to amend the UI is considered bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is executed before the subsequent `<div class='check-media'></div>` is even rendered (it is below in the DOM). You need to wait, until the DOM is ready (loaded) and then you can change it.

To do this, you can use the following snippet (requires jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // your code here
});
```

Comment: Yes, then you need to listen to the resize event. This can be solved by using ``$(window).resize(function() { ... } );`` like @Maddy just answered. But take also a look at the CSS @media queries. This is much simpler done with plain CSS (e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add script in `$( window ).resize(function()`

**Or**

add script in bottom means after body.

```js
$( window ).resize(function() {
    if($('.check-media').width() <= 768) {
        console.log('You are in width: 768px');
    }else{
        console.log('You are out of width: 768px');
    }

    if($(window).width() < 768) {
        console.log('screen.width is LESS then 768px');
        $('.check-media').css({"background-color":"blue"});
    } else {
        console.log('screen.width is MORE then 768px');
        $('.check-media').css({"background-color":"red"});
    }
    });
```

```css
  .check-media{
        width:500px;
        background-color:gray;
    }
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<div class='check-media'>check-media contentn</div>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your script inside.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    write script here!
})
```

Or, check the code below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .check-media{
        width:500px;
        background-color:gray;
    }
</style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    if($('.check-media').width() <= 768) {
        console.log('You are in width: 768px');
    }else{
        console.log('You are out of width: 768px');
    }

    if($(window).width() < 768) {
        console.log('screen.width is LESS then 768px');
        $('.check-media').css({"background-color":"blue"});
    } else {
        console.log('screen.width is MORE then 768px');
        $('.check-media').css({"background-color":"red"});
    }
    });
</script>

</head>

<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<div class='check-media'>check-media contentn</div>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```